# Solidify modifier not filling evenly

Tags: modifiers, solidify-modifier

I am trying to use the solidify modifier to add wall thickness to this kinda curved box I am modeling, but I don't know why the object is not filling evenly across all edges. (fixed!)

Also, I already applied the modifier to one-half of it, but is there a way I could go back and see the details of it? I don't remember the thickness I applied to it, but I need the top and bottom pieces to be even. The two pieces were bisected from one original object btw. (still need help w this)

Would really appreciate any sort of help because I'm new to blender and losing my mind. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you applied the scale in Object mode?

Comment: @moonboots you're my savior thanks so much i didnt realize it was such a simple fix

Comment: If you want to ask another question in future please embed the images directly into your question rather than making us click on links to see them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the scale of your object in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)